Why would krakens go to the surface?
The mighty kraken, Architeuthis Colossus. This giant of the deep sea measures 30-40 meters long with fully extended tentacles, feeding on whatever it can grab and fit into its mouth, including fish, smaller squid, whale carcasses, and even baby whales. However, the kraken is equally a scourge on the surface world. Many a fisherman fears being blown out to sea lest they get pulled under by a tentacle rising from the deep sea. Tales of warships damaged in battle losing sailors one by one to the menace from below. My question is, why would such a well-adapted deep sea predator bother travelling to surface waters and create such an aura of fear around itself? The technology level is at the late medieval period.

Because it likes to... kraken the waves! Ba-dum CHA!

Because someone released it?

Because the latter fire [is heating] the deep https://poets.org/poem/kraken

Out of curiosity. What else.

Apparently, I was mistaken. "kraken the waves! Ba-dum CHA!" was a very relevant comment and I was wrong to raise a flag. That's why it was declined and this eloquent pun will remain here. My apologies.

Since your question is tagged biology...
Your kraken isn't based on the physiology of a giant squid, which uses gills to diffuse oxygen from water. Rather, it's based on the biology of a whale, which has lungs and therefore must surface to breathe.
And you want a whale-like-kraken. The largest giant squid ever recorded was only 43 feet (13 meters), although scientists think it could get up to 66 feet (20 meters). Compare this to the Blue Whale which can grow to 100 feet (30 meters) and weigh up to a surface-ship-crushing 200 tons (181 tonnes).
The advantages of lungs are...

The ability to attack surface vessels with impunity.
Higher energy access with faster and greater oxygen access.
A ravening hunger due to that higher energy.
A significant irritation with humans competing in its traditional fishing ranges.

Keep in mind...
What your kraken might look like is a giant squid with enormous tentacles and lungs. The biology is whale-like. Your kraken is kraken-like.

Could there be a creature that needs to surface only every couple of days to take some serious oxygen replenishment, while in the rest of its time underwater getting enough oxygen through gills/... to slow down the depletion?

@user2962533 Gills are a costly disadvantage for a creature with lungs. There's a reason that air breathing mammals like whales, seals, and dolphins were able to outcompete highly evolved filled competitors.

@user2962533 Well... worldbuilding isn't scientific genetic engineering. The basic rule of evolution is that given enough time almost anything is possible. Personally, I'm not a fan of trying to crowbar everything into science.

@user2962533 Axotl have both gills and lungs. Some species of newts can absorb oxygen thru their skin allowing them to 'breath' underwater and so operate under water at a reduced metabolic rate. Lungfish have both lungs and gills. Mudskippers abbsorb oxygen thru their skin when they are outside of water. So the answer to this question is yes.. it does exist.

Whales can stay submerged for a couple of hours. A greater blood volume and/or an alien substance better than haemoglobin for storing oxygen would give it a couple of days. BTW we have manufactured such substances: perfluoroalkanes. It's very hard to see how biology could manufacture those, but as proof of concept? Also BTW, birds have a haemoglobin variant better than mammals, which is why they can fly at altitudes where humans would be dying of hypoxia.

Cat-nip. (Kraken-nip really.)
Everything in the oceans tastes salty and fishy (sea-urchins being the exception, they taste of something quite different and unmentionable), even the seaweed is a bit samey if eaten day after day.
During the late medieval period, sea trade was expanding throughout the world - anything from gold, silver through herbs and spices.
My idea is that the Kraken can not resist the delicious spicy treats in the cargo: black pepper, cloves, nutmeg, cinnamon, and mace - maybe even a bit of tea. The key one perhaps being sugar.
This is like a flavour explosion in the kraken's mouth - and has the added draw of causing a kind of euphoric narcosis - i.e. it's addictive. They enjoy their sugar rush, perhaps giving them a burst of hyperactive frenzy to boot.
Naturally the Kraken will take down anything that potentially contains the precious cargo, regardless of what is actually on board - sometimes it's gunpowder, nasty salty bitter taste, makes its burps sulfurous and its farts stink - but there's only one way to find out what's on board.

I would add that Sugar would likely be the one that is nearly guaranteed on ships attacked by a Kraken because of its use as a food preservative (By removing water from food.).

Not to mention all that tasty red meat - rats, ship's cats, humans, and maybe any cattle being moved.

Spices can be addictive, too. Pepper, chili and clove for example.

The only realistic reason would be pursuing prey species (probably on an opportunistic or season basis) or as part of their breeding cycle.
A simple example could be whale migrations. During certain times of the year large whale migrations pass over the Krakens normal deep water feeding grounds and generations of Krakens have learned to take advantage of this seasonal bounty to supplement their normal food sources deeper in the ocean. The whales in turn try to evade this predator by going 'silent' and communicating as little as possible during this dangerous part of their annual migration.
Alternatively you could go with female Kraken's needing to rise to the surface to give birth because the baby Kraken are born 'live' (not as eggs)  and it's easier for the young to find food closer to their size near the surface where they're also safe from predation by other, larger Krakens (if not other predators). In this they are a rather  like modern salt water crocodiles because as juveniles their worst enemy is also larger adult crocs.
Possible reason for attacking vessels
Since female Krakens are also highly protective/aggressive during the birthing process if a ship happens to be passing by? In addition some if not all (teenage) Krakens learn before they return to the depths that 'food' can sometimes be swept off the top of the floating pieces of wood they cross paths with from time to time. And while as they get larger this is not enough too sustain them it is a sometimes useful supplement to their normal surface diet of fish and seals etc before they grow large enough (tentacles crossed) to safely return to the deep.
EDIT: If Krakens are egg layers it would still make sense for them to release their eggs near the surface where there is more food for the young and less chance of them being eaten by adults than in the depths. IF mating takes place near the surface as well? Then you can add male aggression to the list of reasons Krakens might attack ships. The male Krakens might become aggressive if 'interrupted' during courtship by a passing ship and/or regard that vessel as a potential threat or rival for the females attention.

Squid are known for breeding once and dying after reproducing and producing a lot of offspring.  This protectiveness of offspring doesn't make sense.

@Monty Wild perhaps Kraken being much larger are different especially as food is harder to find in the colder depths and animals that do live at there like certain species of shark for example are extremely long lived. That aside even if they do only breed once the female may still need to rise to the surface for the reasons given. And it's not so much about protecting her young as protecting herself because she is vulnerable during the birth process. Any 'protection' given to the young lasts only as long as it takes to beak out of the birth sack and start freely swimming on their own.

Squid and octopi typically lay eggs and then die after starving themselves.  Birth would be easy, since the eggs (or even live offspring) would be small and plentiful.

@Monty Wild Its a fictional setting. I'm trying to come up with believable biological reasons for the animals to leave the deep oceans and interact with humans.

if kraken are not that intelligent they could easily be confusing ships for whales,  whales hang out at the surface aterall. Whales are fatty treats, but then they take a bite, which is why you get survivors. Imagine if you took a bite of what you think is the perfect donut and it was made of carboard and sand. The ship is already trashed but most of it gets left behind.

@MontyWild There are actually some species of Octopus, another cephalopod, that do breed multiple times throughout their life. the Larger Pacific Striped Octopus (en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Larger_Pacific_striped_octopus) and the Lesser Pacific Striped Octopus. So conceivably squid could pull off a similar thing

There is a wonderful theory in many works of fiction as to why a monstrous creature would suddenly appear and wreak havoc...
The Kraken is running away from something even more big and scary in the deep ocean
Let us assume that there is an even more terrible creature that feeds on the Kraken - and that sometimes when this creature hunts the Kraken - in a last ditch defensive move, the Kraken bolts for the surface.
Why does this other creature not simply follow the Kraken to the surface? Well - maybe it is so well-adapted to life in the deep Ocean that it can't swim to the surface.
Theories could include:

It will overheat in the warm water
The decreased water pressure will cause it to suffer the Bends or similar.
It gets blinded by the light near the surface and cannot see
It cannot move properly with the decreased pressure

Why a Kraken near the Surface will attack shipping?
Two main reasons:

It is paniced and attacking anything it sees as a potential threat
Swimming for its life uses a lot of energy, it is hungry and exhausted and goes for the biggest thing it can eat to replenish its energy.


The need to poop
Depending on what tone you are going for, you may consider they can only poop at the surface, where there is less water pressure. This actually happens with whales, leading to a well-studied phenomena called the whale pump (1, 2, 3). Basically, whales eat animals at the bottom of the ocean and poop near the surface, which means nutrients that naturally fall downwards via gravity are brought upwards by whales. While at the surface, krakens could reach out and grab any passing meals, such as human ships.

Feeding Frenzy
Krakens are largely deep water adapted (so poor eyesight), sound and smell hunters, who are largely predators of whales. They're also somewhat scavengers, lured in by the sound of distressed whales, for easy pickings. What humans normally interpret as one Kraken is actually a small pack, descending on a single target.
Now, this is all fine - ships aren't interesting to them. Until humans start whaling. Now, you've got loads of angry, hurt whale noises coming from a region of the sea, and this wooden thing that reaks of delicious whale. What's a kraken to do? Driven into a frenzy by the smell of whale, the kraken pod smashes the ship to pieces attempting to get to it.
What is worse is that they start to associate ship sounds with whales, too. And these wooden morsels with the tasty, easy prey in them also smell like, well, burning whale. There's these bright lights on the side of them too, which really, really smell like burning whale.
So until your civilization starts whaling, everything is fine. And then, with whale oil lamps, and whaling ships, the kraken get drawn in.

In some literature, there is the concept that Mankind, through hubris or ignorance, has in some way altered the balance of nature or angered the gods, and thereby brought punishment on himself. In this case, the punishment is merely the sin in its truest form, a kind of poetic justice that is inherent to the nature of the offense committed.
Perhaps your medieval sailors have been hunting whales or overfishing, and have depleted the stocks of its traditional prey, forcing it to come to the surface in search of new food sources - which they find in the form of small, defenceless mammals who for some reason insist on traversing the open sea in large numbers inside wooden containers which the Kraken can easily break open. Or perhaps they have done something else to inadvertently disrupt the deep water ecosystem, such as dumping their most toxic alchemical byproducts into "the deepest depths of the ocean", which just happens to be where the Kraken would normally live out their entire lifespan without ever needing to concern themselves with the surface world. Maybe their blacksmiths have burned so much coal that they have caused a change in ocean temperatures, forcing the Kraken to find new habitats closer to the surface.

TL,DR: Because the humans are there, and they're easy prey.
There's a saying in the movie industry, 'Never work with animals or kids', though many directors ignore this... even though doing either means more work.  There's another saying, 'Never work with animals and kids' because working with both at the same time is even harder.  Especially when the animals you're working with are predators like lions and tigers.
On the movie Gladiator, the big cats that were on the set had been trained to deal with adult handlers and actors, but their handlers were very nervous when Spencer Treat Clark (who was around 12 years old at the time) was required to be on set with the cats, to the point where big panes of glass were placed between him and the animals.  Why was this?  Because big cats love kids the way that housecats love mice.  The smaller and the more helpless the animal or person, the more likely the predator is to go after it.  Even if it's trained.
So, by extension, maybe the kraken do eat things as big as whales... but human sailors - especially when they're in the water or their ship is crippled - are just such easy, tempting prey that the kraken can't resist gobbling them up.
Humans are the snack-food of the marine world, especially for something as big as a kraken.

If they didn’t want to tempt the animals, maybe they shouldn’t have called the kid Treat…

As an aside, apparently humans don't have a high enough fat content (blubber) to be appetizing to most marine predators. Which is why most shark bites are one-and-done. They thought we were a Seal, found out we weren't, declined seconds. USS Indianapolis not withstanding.

They're sentient.
Krakens eat baby whales and whale carcasses. Humans are hunting whales and taking the carcasses with them. The krakens are smart enough to understand that this is happening and want to stop it. They wreck ships and drag humans beneath the waves in order to drive humans away from the more bounteous areas where the most whales live. The krakens know the humans are afraid, and they plan their actions to enhance this, for example by leaving some sailors alive to tell the tale. Their intelligence also makes them a particularly deadly adversary.
Intelligent krakens are not so implausible in my opinion. An animal that size will have a large brain just because brain size tends to be roughly proportional to body size, and we know that molluscs (particularly octopuses) can be very intelligent animals.

Homo occidentalis has worked over the centuries on their standards of living to reduce the discomfort experienced by homo sapiens sapiens' natural way of living. Wild beasts, weather, food scarcity, all these nuisances have been dealt with and many of Homo occidentalis now leave in the belief that brown cows make chocolate milk, blueberries can be naturally eaten all year long and avocados, pineapples and coconuts pop up naturally on the shelves of supermarket of Nordic countries.
Despite all these benefits of a sheltered life, to which Homo occidentalis is very well adapted, many among them pay good money to go spend few weeks of each year experiencing those very discomforts they run away all the rest of the year: walking under the rain they built an unstable tent on a cold ground, fight through the misery of a drenched camp to warm up some water and eat a soup which in the city they would gladly throw at the waiter who served it, if it wasn't for some decency they would like to abide to.
Same for your krakens: those who venture up near the sea/atmosphere interface are the oddballs who like experiencing the thrill of discomfort for a short time to better enjoy their comforts for the rest of their year.

Shiny things make shiny nests
Some animals need to create the most beautiful nests to attract mates. Take pufferfish and birds-of-paradise, for example.
The kraken is no different. Those floating objects on the surface — empty hazelnuts at best for it — abound with treasures beyond anything found in the sea. Surely, Ms. Kraken won’t be able to resist!

Whaling has upset the balance of nature
Giant squids normally stay deep for two reason.  The first is that there is enough food in the deep parts of the ocean that they have no reason to surface, and the second is that staying deep keeps them safe from sperm whales which naturally hunt them.  However, years of whaling have reduced the population of sperm whales to nearly nothing allowing the population of Krakens to grow out of control. This leads the Krakens to overhunt and deplete their deep water food supply while simultaneously making hunting near the surface safer.
By the time Krakens become desperate enough to hunt near the surface, they are already starving and desperate making them willing to attack anything they can find, including human ships.
